# How to Apply Gradient using CSS?

Tags: html, ios, css, objective-c

I am in an iOS Project. I use UIWebView which supports HTML CSS JS. I have a background. I want to make Gradient Black to White, where It must be transparent.

Actually I will change background in Future, so it must be that it will show background Image with its transparency (gradient).

Where Image is on of UIImageView on whole of background, and UIWebView is a subview.

if I use

```
    NSString *htmlStringQuestion = [NSString stringWithFormat:
    @"<style type='text/css'>* 
    {
        padding:0px; margin:0px;
    }
    div.ContentWrapper {
        width:100%%; height:100%%;
        text-align:center;
        display:table;
    }
    div.ContentArea {
        display:table-cell; 
        vertical-align:middle; 
        padding:0 5%%; 
        background:none;
        background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
        color: #00000; 
        font-size:30; 
        font-family: Baskerville;
    }
    </style>
    <div class='ContentWrapper'><div class='ContentArea'>
        <p>Hello</p>
    </div>
    </div>", htmlString];
```

It looks as

[image]

Any suggestion.

But I want something black to white, from TOP to WHITE.

Comment: I've never done iOS projects but from a pure CSS perspective, it seems like you are looking for a gradient like in [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kapezgnu/). It is a gradient where the color goes from a semi-transparent black at top to a semi-transparent white at bottom and the background is still visible. If this helps you then let me know and I'll add it as answer. (*Note:* The part within the CSS tab will go into the `<style>` tag in your code.)

Answer (score 1):

```
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(0,0,0,1) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%); /* Chrome10-25,Safari5.1-6 */
background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  rgba(0,0,0,1) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%); /* W3C, IE10+, FF16+, Chrome26+, Opera12+, Safari7+ */
```

**Note:** 
I used [Ultimate CSS Gradient Generator](http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/) to get this code. You can use it to generate any css gradient you like.
I'm not affiliated with that site.

Comment: I have removed the non-relevant parts of my answer. Older versions of Safari and UIWebView may need the `-webkit-` prefix. Newer versions (see in code comments) will work with the non-prefixed version.